# ionic 2 - one to many services

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic2

I have a list of users which every user can have zero, one or many files , so the relation between users table and files table is one to many

In my backend project I can have the list of users and files as a list in every user entity .. And in my front end I want to show the user details with his attachments (files)

this is my code :

```
user: {username?: string, password?: string, files: {docfile?: string}} = {};

    constructor(public navParams: NavParams) {
        this.user = navParams.data;
    }
```

and this is the html part :

```
<ion-content padding>

        <ion-label>username : </ion-label>
        {{user.username}}
    </p>

    <p>
        <ion-label>Documents : </ion-label>
        <img src={{user.documents.docfile}}  />

    </p>

</ion-content>
```

what should I do please ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your html you're referencing `user.documents.docfile` while in your ts you set your filestring to be `user.files.docfile`.

I don't know what you're calling the `docfile` in your backend but I guess it's `files`.

So changing your html to `user.files.docfile` should work. (if it's an image)

if it's not an image you won't get it as `files: {docfile?: string}}` but as `files: [{docfile?: string}]` in that case you can do the following in your html

```
    <ion-label>Documents : </ion-label>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let file of user.files">
        <img [src]="file.docfile"/> <!-- if it's an image -->
      </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
```

Comment: open up your browser's console and show the error in the console please (ctrl + shift + i   in chrome)

Comment: it works I had to quit ionic and run ionic serve again , thanks